# Check gate errors of old jobs in IBMq

Tags: qiskit, ibm-q-experience

How can I check the gates errors and other device configurations of a past set of jobs ran in IBMQ? I have the line

```
retrieve_job = provider.backend.retrieve_job(job_id)
```

so somewhere in this `retrieve_job` variable this information should be available, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use [`retrieve_job.properties()`](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.providers.ibmq.job.IBMQJob.properties.html) method to get the backend properties snapshot at the time when the job is run. This method returns [`BackendProperties`](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.providers.models.BackendProperties.html) class object.

And from there you can use the methods of `BackendProperties` get the details of the backend. Here I am using a job I ran on `ibmq_quito` in 2021 as examples.

### Get qubit properties

You can get the `T1`, `T2`, `readout_error` etc for qubit 0 like this:

```
retrieve_job.properties().qubit_property(0)
```

Output:

```
{'T1': (8.254176794866777e-05,
  datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 22, 16, 0, 34, tzinfo=tzlocal())),
 'T2': (6.482287466299863e-05,
  datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 22, 4, 7, 16, tzinfo=tzlocal())),
 'frequency': (5300543103.027277,
  datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 22, 16, 20, 7, tzinfo=tzlocal())),
 'anharmonicity': (-331480169.4030778,
  datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 22, 16, 20, 7, tzinfo=tzlocal())),
 'readout_error': (0.06799999999999995,
  datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 22, 4, 6, 18, tzinfo=tzlocal())),
 'prob_meas0_prep1': (0.09619999999999995,
  datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 22, 4, 6, 18, tzinfo=tzlocal())),
 'prob_meas1_prep0': (0.0398,
  datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 22, 4, 6, 18, tzinfo=tzlocal())),
 'readout_length': (5.35111111111111e-06,
  datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 22, 4, 6, 18, tzinfo=tzlocal()))}
```

### Get gate error

```
retrieve_job.properties().gate_error('cx', [0,1])
```

Output:

```
0.00823348793137102
```

### Get a dictionary format representation

You can also use the `to_dict` method to get a python dictionary representation of `BackenProperties`. From there you can print the dictionary to see all the properties or to extract the information via dictionary keywords.

```
retrieve_job.properties().to_dict()
```

Output:

```
{'backend_name': 'ibmq_quito',
 'backend_version': '1.1.3',
 'last_update_date': datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 22, 16, 20, 7, tzinfo=tzlocal()),
 'qubits': [[{'date': datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 22, 16, 0, 34, tzinfo=tzlocal()),
    'name': 'T1',
    'unit': 'us',
    'value': 82.54176794866777},
   {'date': datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 22, 4, 7, 16, tzinfo=tzlocal()),
    'name': 'T2',
    'unit': 'us',
    'value': 64.82287466299863},
   {'date': datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 22, 16, 20, 7, tzinfo=tzlocal()),
    'name': 'frequency',
    'unit': 'GHz',
    'value': 5.300543103027277},
   {'date': datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 22, 16, 20, 7, tzinfo=tzlocal()),
    'name': 'anharmonicity',
    'unit': 'GHz',
    'value': -0.3314801694030778},
   {'date': datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 22, 4, 6, 18, tzinfo=tzlocal()),
    'name': 'readout_error',
    'unit': '',
    'value': 0.06799999999999995},
   {'date': datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 22, 4, 6, 18, tzinfo=tzlocal()),
    'name': 'prob_meas0_prep1',
    'unit': '',
    'value': 0.09619999999999995},
   {'date': datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 22, 4, 6, 18, tzinfo=tzlocal()),
    'name': 'prob_meas1_prep0',
    'unit': '',
    'value': 0.0398},
   {'date': datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 22, 4, 6, 18, tzinfo=tzlocal()),
    'name': 'readout_length',
    'unit': 'ns',
    'value': 5351.11111111111}],
  [{'date': datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 22, 9, 53, 49, tzinfo=tzlocal()),
    'name': 'T1',
    'unit': 'us',
    'value': 103.72828082775345},
   {'date': datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 22, 4, 8, 12, tzinfo=tzlocal()),
    'name': 'T2',
    'unit': 'us',
    'value': 131.06382709733492},
   {'date': datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 22, 16, 20, 7, tzinfo=tzlocal()),
    'name': 'frequency',
    'unit': 'GHz',
    'value': 5.08063089478259},
   {'date': datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 22, 16, 20, 7, tzinfo=tzlocal()),
    'name': 'anharmonicity',
    'unit': 'GHz',
    'value': -0.3192453770191231},
   {'date': datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 22, 4, 6, 18, tzinfo=tzlocal()),
    'name': 'readout_error',
    'unit': '',
    'value': 0.02429999999999999},
   {'date': datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 22, 4, 6, 18, tzinfo=tzlocal()),
    'name': 'prob_meas0_prep1',
    'unit': '',
    'value': 0.03859999999999997},
   {'date': datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 22, 4, 6, 18, tzinfo=tzlocal()),
    'name': 'prob_meas1_prep0',
    'unit': '',
    'value': 0.01},
   {'date': datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 22, 4, 6, 18, tzinfo=tzlocal()),
    'name': 'readout_length',
    'unit': 'ns',
    'value': 5351.11111111111}],
  [{'date': datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 22, 16, 0, 34, tzinfo=tzlocal()),
    'name': 'T1',
    'unit': 'us',
    'value': 82.10307586455073},
   {'date': datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 22, 4, 7, 16, tzinfo=tzlocal()),
    'name': 'T2',
    'unit': 'us',
    'value': 108.81451906220688},
   {'date': datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 22, 16, 20, 7, tzinfo=tzlocal()),
    'name': 'frequency',
    'unit': 'GHz',
    'value': 5.322266665992028},
   {'date': datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 22, 16, 20, 7, tzinfo=tzlocal()),
    'name': 'anharmonicity',
    'unit': 'GHz',
    'value': -0.33231656282971167},
   {'date': datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 22, 4, 6, 18, tzinfo=tzlocal()),
    'name': 'readout_error',
    'unit': '',
    'value': 0.028100000000000014},
   {'date': datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 22, 4, 6, 18, tzinfo=tzlocal()),
    'name': 'prob_meas0_prep1',
    'unit': '',
    'value': 0.04700000000000004},
   {'date': datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 22, 4, 6, 18, tzinfo=tzlocal()),
    'name': 'prob_meas1_prep0',
    'unit': '',
    'value': 0.0092},
   {'date': datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 22, 4, 6, 18, tzinfo=tzlocal()),
    'name': 'readout_length',
    'unit': 'ns',
    'value': 5351.11111111111}],
  [{'date': datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 22, 16, 0, 34, tzinfo=tzlocal()),
    'name': 'T1',
    'unit': 'us',
    'value': 100.55820874143706},
   {'date': datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 12, 4, 9, 8, tzinfo=tzlocal()),
    'name': 'T2',
    'unit': 'us',
    'value': 23.271712661997793},
   {'date': datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 22, 16, 20, 7, tzinfo=tzlocal()),
    'name': 'frequency',
    'unit': 'GHz',
    'value': 5.163709842447912},
   {'date': datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 22, 16, 20, 7, tzinfo=tzlocal()),
    'name': 'anharmonicity',
    'unit': 'GHz',
    'value': -0.33508064939515236},
   {'date': datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 22, 4, 6, 18, tzinfo=tzlocal()),
    'name': 'readout_error',
    'unit': '',
    'value': 0.021499999999999964},
   {'date': datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 22, 4, 6, 18, tzinfo=tzlocal()),
    'name': 'prob_meas0_prep1',
    'unit': '',
    'value': 0.034599999999999964},
   {'date': datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 22, 4, 6, 18, tzinfo=tzlocal()),
    'name': 'prob_meas1_prep0',
    'unit': '',
    'value': 0.0084},
   {'date': datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 22, 4, 6, 18, tzinfo=tzlocal()),
    'name': 'readout_length',
    'unit': 'ns',
    'value': 5351.11111111111}],
  [{'date': datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 22, 16, 3, 29, tzinfo=tzlocal()),
    'name': 'T1',
    'unit': 'us',
    'value': 124.54980489073562},
   {'date': datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 22, 4, 8, 12, tzinfo=tzlocal()),
    'name': 'T2',
    'unit': 'us',
    'value': 265.2313321816987},
   {'date': datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 22, 16, 20, 7, tzinfo=tzlocal()),
    'name': 'frequency',
    'unit': 'GHz',
    'value': 5.052387736754675},
   {'date': datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 22, 16, 20, 7, tzinfo=tzlocal()),
    'name': 'anharmonicity',
    'unit': 'GHz',
    'value': -0.3192628614050085},
   {'date': datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 22, 4, 6, 18, tzinfo=tzlocal()),
    'name': 'readout_error',
    'unit': '',
    'value': 0.020100000000000007},
   {'date': datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 22, 4, 6, 18, tzinfo=tzlocal()),
    'name': 'prob_meas0_prep1',
    'unit': '',
    'value': 0.03259999999999996},
   {'date': datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 22, 4, 6, 18, tzinfo=tzlocal()),
    'name': 'prob_meas1_prep0',
    'unit': '',
    'value': 0.0076},
   {'date': datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 22, 4, 6, 18, tzinfo=tzlocal()),
    'name': 'readout_length',
    'unit': 'ns',
    'value': 5351.11111111111}]],
 'gates': [{'qubits': [0],
   'gate': 'id',
   'parameters': [{'date': datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 22, 4, 9, 25, tzinfo=tzlocal()),
     'name': 'gate_error',
     'unit': '',
     'value': 0.0004770946041833094},
    {'date': datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 22, 16, 20, 7, tzinfo=tzlocal()),
     'name': 'gate_length',
     'unit': 'ns',
     'value': 35.55555555555556}],
   'name': 'id0'},
  {'qubits': [1],
   'gate': 'id',
   'parameters': [{'date': datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 22, 4, 9, 25, tzinfo=tzlocal()),
     'name': 'gate_error',
     'unit': '',
     'value': 0.0003120081069207972},
    {'date': datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 22, 16, 20, 7, tzinfo=tzlocal()),
     'name': 'gate_length',
     'unit': 'ns',
     'value': 35.55555555555556}],
   'name': 'id1'},
  {'qubits': [2],
   'gate': 'id',
   'parameters': [{'date': datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 22, 4, 9, 25, tzinfo=tzlocal()),
     'name': 'gate_error',
     'unit': '',
     'value': 0.0009411051017017428},
    {'date': datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 22, 16, 20, 7, tzinfo=tzlocal()),
     'name': 'gate_length',
     'unit': 'ns',
     'value': 35.55555555555556}],
   'name': 'id2'},
  {'qubits': [3],
   'gate': 'id',
   'parameters': [{'date': datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 22, 4, 9, 25, tzinfo=tzlocal()),
     'name': 'gate_error',
     'unit': '',
     'value': 0.0005509607849932694},
    {'date': datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 22, 16, 20, 7, tzinfo=tzlocal()),
     'name': 'gate_length',
     'unit': 'ns',
     'value': 35.55555555555556}],
   'name': 'id3'},
  {'qubits': [4],
   'gate': 'id',
   'parameters': [{'date': datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 22, 4, 9, 25, tzinfo=tzlocal()),
     'name': 'gate_error',
     'unit': '',
     'value': 0.0007643172751559529},
    {'date': datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 22, 16, 20, 7, tzinfo=tzlocal()),
     'name': 'gate_length',
     'unit': 'ns',
     'value': 35.55555555555556}],
   'name': 'id4'},
  {'qubits': [0],
   'gate': 'rz',
   'parameters': [{'date': datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 22, 16, 20, 7, tzinfo=tzlocal()),
     'name': 'gate_error',
     'unit': '',
     'value': 0},
    {'date': datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 22, 16, 20, 7, tzinfo=tzlocal()),
     'name': 'gate_length',
     'unit': 'ns',
     'value': 0}],
   'name': 'rz0'},
  {'qubits': [1],
   'gate': 'rz',
   'parameters': [{'date': datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 22, 16, 20, 7, tzinfo=tzlocal()),
     'name': 'gate_error',
     'unit': '',
     'value': 0},
    {'date': datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 22, 16, 20, 7, tzinfo=tzlocal()),
     'name': 'gate_length',
     'unit': 'ns',
     'value': 0}],
   'name': 'rz1'},
  {'qubits': [2],
   'gate': 'rz',
   'parameters': [{'date': datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 22, 16, 20, 7, tzinfo=tzlocal()),
     'name': 'gate_error',
     'unit': '',
     'value': 0},
    {'date': datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 22, 16, 20, 7, tzinfo=tzlocal()),
     'name': 'gate_length',
     'unit': 'ns',
     'value': 0}],
   'name': 'rz2'},
  {'qubits': [3],
   'gate': 'rz',
   'parameters': [{'date': datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 22, 16, 20, 7, tzinfo=tzlocal()),
     'name': 'gate_error',
     'unit': '',
     'value': 0},
    {'date': datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 22, 16, 20, 7, tzinfo=tzlocal()),
     'name': 'gate_length',
     'unit': 'ns',
     'value': 0}],
   'name': 'rz3'},
  {'qubits': [4],
   'gate': 'rz',
   'parameters': [{'date': datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 22, 16, 20, 7, tzinfo=tzlocal()),
     'name': 'gate_error',
     'unit': '',
     'value': 0},
    {'date': datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 22, 16, 20, 7, tzinfo=tzlocal()),
     'name': 'gate_length',
     'unit': 'ns',
     'value': 0}],
   'name': 'rz4'},
  {'qubits': [0],
   'gate': 'sx',
   'parameters': [{'date': datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 22, 4, 9, 25, tzinfo=tzlocal()),
     'name': 'gate_error',
     'unit': '',
     'value': 0.0004770946041833094},
    {'date': datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 22, 16, 20, 7, tzinfo=tzlocal()),
     'name': 'gate_length',
     'unit': 'ns',
     'value': 35.55555555555556}],
   'name': 'sx0'},
  {'qubits': [1],
   'gate': 'sx',
   'parameters': [{'date': datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 22, 4, 9, 25, tzinfo=tzlocal()),
     'name': 'gate_error',
     'unit': '',
     'value': 0.0003120081069207972},
    {'date': datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 22, 16, 20, 7, tzinfo=tzlocal()),
     'name': 'gate_length',
     'unit': 'ns',
     'value': 35.55555555555556}],
   'name': 'sx1'},
  {'qubits': [2],
   'gate': 'sx',
   'parameters': [{'date': datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 22, 4, 9, 25, tzinfo=tzlocal()),
     'name': 'gate_error',
     'unit': '',
     'value': 0.0009411051017017428},
    {'date': datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 22, 16, 20, 7, tzinfo=tzlocal()),
     'name': 'gate_length',
     'unit': 'ns',
     'value': 35.55555555555556}],
   'name': 'sx2'},
  {'qubits': [3],
   'gate': 'sx',
   'parameters': [{'date': datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 22, 4, 9, 25, tzinfo=tzlocal()),
     'name': 'gate_error',
     'unit': '',
     'value': 0.0005509607849932694},
    {'date': datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 22, 16, 20, 7, tzinfo=tzlocal()),
     'name': 'gate_length',
     'unit': 'ns',
     'value': 35.55555555555556}],
   'name': 'sx3'},
  {'qubits': [4],
   'gate': 'sx',
   'parameters': [{'date': datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 22, 4, 9, 25, tzinfo=tzlocal()),
     'name': 'gate_error',
     'unit': '',
     'value': 0.0007643172751559529},
    {'date': datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 22, 16, 20, 7, tzinfo=tzlocal()),
     'name': 'gate_length',
     'unit': 'ns',
     'value': 35.55555555555556}],
   'name': 'sx4'},
  {'qubits': [0],
   'gate': 'x',
   'parameters': [{'date': datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 22, 4, 9, 25, tzinfo=tzlocal()),
     'name': 'gate_error',
     'unit': '',
     'value': 0.0004770946041833094},
    {'date': datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 22, 16, 20, 7, tzinfo=tzlocal()),
     'name': 'gate_length',
     'unit': 'ns',
     'value': 35.55555555555556}],
   'name': 'x0'},
  {'qubits': [1],
   'gate': 'x',
   'parameters': [{'date': datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 22, 4, 9, 25, tzinfo=tzlocal()),
     'name': 'gate_error',
     'unit': '',
     'value': 0.0003120081069207972},
    {'date': datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 22, 16, 20, 7, tzinfo=tzlocal()),
     'name': 'gate_length',
     'unit': 'ns',
     'value': 35.55555555555556}],
   'name': 'x1'},
  {'qubits': [2],
   'gate': 'x',
   'parameters': [{'date': datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 22, 4, 9, 25, tzinfo=tzlocal()),
     'name': 'gate_error',
     'unit': '',
     'value': 0.0009411051017017428},
    {'date': datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 22, 16, 20, 7, tzinfo=tzlocal()),
     'name': 'gate_length',
     'unit': 'ns',
     'value': 35.55555555555556}],
   'name': 'x2'},
  {'qubits': [3],
   'gate': 'x',
   'parameters': [{'date': datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 22, 4, 9, 25, tzinfo=tzlocal()),
     'name': 'gate_error',
     'unit': '',
     'value': 0.0005509607849932694},
    {'date': datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 22, 16, 20, 7, tzinfo=tzlocal()),
     'name': 'gate_length',
     'unit': 'ns',
     'value': 35.55555555555556}],
   'name': 'x3'},
  {'qubits': [4],
   'gate': 'x',
   'parameters': [{'date': datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 22, 4, 9, 25, tzinfo=tzlocal()),
     'name': 'gate_error',
     'unit': '',
     'value': 0.0007643172751559529},
    {'date': datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 22, 16, 20, 7, tzinfo=tzlocal()),
     'name': 'gate_length',
     'unit': 'ns',
     'value': 35.55555555555556}],
   'name': 'x4'},
  {'qubits': [3, 4],
   'gate': 'cx',
   'parameters': [{'date': datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 22, 4, 30, 17, tzinfo=tzlocal()),
     'name': 'gate_error',
     'unit': '',
     'value': 0.016650728791934744},
    {'date': datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 19, 16, 20, 7, tzinfo=tzlocal()),
     'name': 'gate_length',
     'unit': 'ns',
     'value': 277.3333333333333}],
   'name': 'cx3_4'},
  {'qubits': [4, 3],
   'gate': 'cx',
   'parameters': [{'date': datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 22, 4, 30, 17, tzinfo=tzlocal()),
     'name': 'gate_error',
     'unit': '',
     'value': 0.016650728791934744},
    {'date': datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 19, 16, 20, 7, tzinfo=tzlocal()),
     'name': 'gate_length',
     'unit': 'ns',
     'value': 312.88888888888886}],
   'name': 'cx4_3'},
  {'qubits': [1, 3],
   'gate': 'cx',
   'parameters': [{'date': datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 22, 4, 25, 33, tzinfo=tzlocal()),
     'name': 'gate_error',
     'unit': '',
     'value': 0.008844502482783928},
    {'date': datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 19, 16, 20, 7, tzinfo=tzlocal()),
     'name': 'gate_length',
     'unit': 'ns',
     'value': 334.22222222222223}],
   'name': 'cx1_3'},
  {'qubits': [3, 1],
   'gate': 'cx',
   'parameters': [{'date': datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 22, 4, 25, 33, tzinfo=tzlocal()),
     'name': 'gate_error',
     'unit': '',
     'value': 0.008844502482783928},
    {'date': datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 19, 16, 20, 7, tzinfo=tzlocal()),
     'name': 'gate_length',
     'unit': 'ns',
     'value': 369.77777777777777}],
   'name': 'cx3_1'},
  {'qubits': [2, 1],
   'gate': 'cx',
   'parameters': [{'date': datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 22, 4, 20, 41, tzinfo=tzlocal()),
     'name': 'gate_error',
     'unit': '',
     'value': 0.010006916885443862},
    {'date': datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 19, 16, 20, 7, tzinfo=tzlocal()),
     'name': 'gate_length',
     'unit': 'ns',
     'value': 263.1111111111111}],
   'name': 'cx2_1'},
  {'qubits': [1, 2],
   'gate': 'cx',
   'parameters': [{'date': datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 22, 4, 20, 41, tzinfo=tzlocal()),
     'name': 'gate_error',
     'unit': '',
     'value': 0.010006916885443862},
    {'date': datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 19, 16, 20, 7, tzinfo=tzlocal()),
     'name': 'gate_length',
     'unit': 'ns',
     'value': 298.66666666666663}],
   'name': 'cx1_2'},
  {'qubits': [0, 1],
   'gate': 'cx',
   'parameters': [{'date': datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 22, 4, 15, 9, tzinfo=tzlocal()),
     'name': 'gate_error',
     'unit': '',
     'value': 0.00823348793137102},
    {'date': datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 19, 16, 20, 7, tzinfo=tzlocal()),
     'name': 'gate_length',
     'unit': 'ns',
     'value': 234.66666666666666}],
   'name': 'cx0_1'},
  {'qubits': [1, 0],
   'gate': 'cx',
   'parameters': [{'date': datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 22, 4, 15, 9, tzinfo=tzlocal()),
     'name': 'gate_error',
     'unit': '',
     'value': 0.00823348793137102},
    {'date': datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 19, 16, 20, 7, tzinfo=tzlocal()),
     'name': 'gate_length',
     'unit': 'ns',
     'value': 270.22222222222223}],
   'name': 'cx1_0'},
  {'qubits': [0],
   'gate': 'reset',
   'parameters': [{'date': datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 22, 16, 20, 7, tzinfo=tzlocal()),
     'name': 'gate_length',
     'unit': 'ns',
     'value': 5920}],
   'name': 'reset0'},
  {'qubits': [1],
   'gate': 'reset',
   'parameters': [{'date': datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 22, 16, 20, 7, tzinfo=tzlocal()),
     'name': 'gate_length',
     'unit': 'ns',
     'value': 5920}],
   'name': 'reset1'},
  {'qubits': [2],
   'gate': 'reset',
   'parameters': [{'date': datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 22, 16, 20, 7, tzinfo=tzlocal()),
     'name': 'gate_length',
     'unit': 'ns',
     'value': 5920}],
   'name': 'reset2'},
  {'qubits': [3],
   'gate': 'reset',
   'parameters': [{'date': datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 22, 16, 20, 7, tzinfo=tzlocal()),
     'name': 'gate_length',
     'unit': 'ns',
     'value': 5920}],
   'name': 'reset3'},
  {'qubits': [4],
   'gate': 'reset',
   'parameters': [{'date': datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 22, 16, 20, 7, tzinfo=tzlocal()),
     'name': 'gate_length',
     'unit': 'ns',
     'value': 5920}],
   'name': 'reset4'}],
 'general': [{'date': datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 22, 16, 20, 7, tzinfo=tzlocal()),
   'name': 'jq_01',
   'unit': 'GHz',
   'value': 0.00186342505350527},
  {'date': datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 22, 16, 20, 7, tzinfo=tzlocal()),
   'name': 'zz_01',
   'unit': 'GHz',
   'value': -7.496747784218088e-05},
  {'date': datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 22, 16, 20, 7, tzinfo=tzlocal()),
   'name': 'jq_13',
   'unit': 'GHz',
   'value': 0.0018230567832240405},
  {'date': datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 22, 16, 20, 7, tzinfo=tzlocal()),
   'name': 'zz_13',
   'unit': 'GHz',
   'value': -4.288984169653279e-05},
  {'date': datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 22, 16, 20, 7, tzinfo=tzlocal()),
   'name': 'jq_34',
   'unit': 'GHz',
   'value': 0.0016159955057034297},
  {'date': datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 22, 16, 20, 7, tzinfo=tzlocal()),
   'name': 'zz_34',
   'unit': 'GHz',
   'value': -3.547813333704521e-05},
  {'date': datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 22, 16, 20, 7, tzinfo=tzlocal()),
   'name': 'jq_12',
   'unit': 'GHz',
   'value': 0.001915672600199012},
  {'date': datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 22, 16, 20, 7, tzinfo=tzlocal()),
   'name': 'zz_12',
   'unit': 'GHz',
   'value': -9.390005618575403e-05}]}
```